# how to get input type is number using form in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

This is my form builder code

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('phoneAlternative', 'number',array('max_length'=>15));
    $builder->add('emailPersonal', 'email');
    $builder->add('addressCurrent', 'textarea');
}
```

This is html markup

```
<input id="employee_phoneAlternative" type="text" maxlength="15" required="required" name="employee[phoneAlternative]" class="valid">
```

Any one suggest me. why input type is giving "text" since, I have given as a number. while building form. how i will get input type as "number" in symfony2 using form builder.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use the form type '[integer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html)', rather than '[number](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html)'.

'number' form types should be used for *floats*, which require a `text` input.

So the correct line of code in your case would be:

```
$builder->add('phoneAlternative', 'integer', array('max_length'=>15));
```

Comment: Beside that: Both `number` and `integer` aren't useful for phone numbers, because users are used to fill in formatted phone numbers like `+49 (30) 123 456`

Comment: use can use Regex constraint for phone numbers

Comment: As a note, latest Symfony versions require 'integer' to be written like: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType::class

Comment: Note that your phone number will be transformed to an int, so `0123` will become `123`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by overriding the form theme template (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html, 'Form theming' section).
In your example, the block to create is 'number_widget':

```
{% block number_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('number') %}
    {{ block('input') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock number_widget %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like that

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
$builder->add('phoneAlternative', 'integer',array('max_length'=>15));
$builder->add('emailPersonal', 'email');
$builder->add('addressCurrent', 'textarea');
}
```

or you can create your form in html.twig using the input

```
 phoneAlternative:   <input type="Number" required>
```